# Recording Mobile Native App Using jmeter

Tags: android, mobile, jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to record Mobile native app using JMeter, below are the steps which I am following:

1. Connect (using Android 6.0) Mobile and Laptop on the same and open network.
2. Update Laptop IP and Port no. in Mobile device.
3. Start recording in Apache JMeter 3.0 using same port no. as set in mobile.
4. Perform the step in the app.

But there is error message in the mobile device which say unable to connect to device.

I have verified ip address and port no. on the device.

I also tried using Blazemeter option- in that it capture URLs no capturing request body?

Can anybody Advice me where the problem can be?

Comment: Could be SSL handshake issue - can you check if you follow the steps mentioned here - http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-record-ios-application-http-requests/ ?

Comment: I have gone through the mentioned steps in above url, but not able to record, the application shows some network related message, and when tried to record basic url in chrome it says - connection time out issue. Can you suggest.

Comment: Have you verified if you can record any browser activity using the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified if you can record any browser activity using the same approach.

And if you can record browser activities, then probably there is any third party sdk which blocks further API calls within your App because you're making proxy calls.

Try with excluding those third party request under "URL Patterns to Exclude" option in HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.